# Error: Argument 'x' passed to 'pad' must be a Tensor or TensorLike, but got 'Tensor'

Tags: react-native, tensorflow.js

I am trying to build an object detection app using react native with a custom model trained from Yolov5, and converted with tensorflowjs (v3.19.0).

My images are in data Url string format (turned into a base64 image format), and I am getting the following error:

```
Error: Argument 'x' passed to 'pad' must be a Tensor or TensorLike, but got 'Tensor'
```

Can anyone help to inspect where the error comes from and how to fix this? (I think it's in the "Processed tensor" section but can't figure out what exactly went wrong)

Here is the full code for my predictions:

```js
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';
import {bundleResourceIO, decodeJpeg} from '@tensorflow/tfjs-react-native';

const modelJSON = require('../assets/web_model/model.json');
const modelWeights = [
  require('../assets/web_model/group1-shard1of7.bin'),
  require('../assets/web_model/group1-shard2of7.bin'),
  require('../assets/web_model/group1-shard3of7.bin'),
  require('../assets/web_model/group1-shard4of7.bin'),
  require('../assets/web_model/group1-shard5of7.bin'),
  require('../assets/web_model/group1-shard6of7.bin'),
  require('../assets/web_model/group1-shard7of7.bin'),
];

const getPredictions = async (dataURL: string) => {
  // As tensorflow gets ready
  await tf.ready();

  // Load model
  const model = await tf.loadGraphModel(
    bundleResourceIO(modelJSON, modelWeights),
  );

  // Make input data
  const imgB64 = dataURL.split(';base64,')[1];
  const imgBuffer = tf.util.encodeString(imgB64, 'base64').buffer;
  const raw = new Uint8Array(imgBuffer);
  const imagesTensor = decodeJpeg(raw);

  // Process input data
  const modelShape: any = model.inputs[0].shape;
  const resolution: [number, number] = modelShape.slice(1, 3);
  let processedTensor = tf.image.resizeBilinear(imagesTensor, [
      inputHeight,
      inputWidth,
    ]) as tf.Tensor<tf.Rank.R3>;
    processedTensor = tf.cast(processedTensor, 'float32');
    processedTensor = tf.div(processedTensor, 255.0);
    processedTensor = tf.reshape(processedTensor, [inputHeight, inputWidth, 3]);
    processedTensor = tf.expandDims(processedTensor, 0);
    
    // Get prediction
    return (await model.executeAsync(processedTensor)) as tf.Tensor[];
};

export default getPredictions;
```

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by moving the whole project to the Expo one, as this was the vanilla React Native. Now the issue is fixed.